# Node.js: resource not getting release when using generic-pool

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using generic-pool npm module and trying to create a pupeteer pool and the destroy method from the factory is not getting called.

I am able to acquire resource but not able to release and destroy is not called.

here are relevant parts of the code

**browser-pool.js**

```
const genericPool = require('generic-pool');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

module.exports = function() {

  const browserParams = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? {
    headless: false,
    devtools: false,
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
  }
  :
  {
    headless: true,
    devtools: false,
    executablePath: 'google-chrome-unstable',
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
  };

  const factory = {
    create: function() {
      return puppeteer.launch(browserParams);
    },
    destroy: function(instance) {
      console.log('closing browser');
      instance.close();
    },
  }

  const opts = {
    max: 2
  };

  return genericPool.createPool(factory, opts);
};
```

**processor.js**

```
const pool = require('./browser-pool');


async function performExport(params){
  const poolInstance = pool();
  const resp = poolInstance.acquire().then(async function(c){
// do processing
   poolInstance.release(c); //***Does not call destroy**
  });
}
```

I am missing something but not sure what. Any help would be really great. Thanks